How to match Sprite3D's collision poly to its billboard transform?
Assume there is a Sprite3D with a Y- billboard flag on.
This sprite3D has a matching CollisionPolygon3D
Collision polygon3D is set up to "look" at the camera with a look_at() function, similar to the Y-billboard.
However, the collision poly and the sprite3D do not match at non-orthogonal angles:

(Angle to the camera is about 45deg)
I understand that Y-billboard flag achieves the "look at the camera" effect with a shader, while look_at() is a spacial matrix transform. Yet, is there a way to align these two?
